# Can I refer to a global variable even if a locally scoped one exists with the same name?

Tags: shell-script, variable

If I have a variable x

```
total=3
```

and then a function

```
function A () {
    local -i total=0
}
```

Is there any way I can update the 'global' total variable `total` from within function `A` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that, in `bash` anyway, you can use `declare` and the `-g`lobal switch to force global scope. Like:

```
total=5
fn(){ local -i total=0
      declare -g total=10
      echo "$total"
};fn
echo "$total"
```

...which prints...

```
0
10
```

Comment: That takes care of assignment, but  how would you print it out?

Comment: @Bratchley - I'm scratching my head at that a little. I really don't like all of these screwy shell-specific commands personally, and tend to use `set` for local value storage in functions. If I figure it out I'll ping you.